# What is the best word for a "nearby time"? Proximate?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a client cancels, I want to ask him to propose another time that is "nearby" to the original date.  Would it be correct to say, "nearby time"?  (I think not.)

I sometimes say, "Let's reschedule to a proximate time."

Is there a better expression?

Comment: Is there a reason to avoid *soon*?

Comment: Unless you deal with a somewhat rareified clientelle, many of them might just look blanly at you when you start talking about "a proximate time" (or they might assume you mean an *approximate* time because punctuality isn't important to you). But what's wrong with ***nearby time***, which you're obviously quite happy to use in your question title?

Comment: *... to a time close to that*?

Comment: "Nearby time" doesn't sound right, @FumbleFingers.  At least not to me.  I'd probably go with "let's reschedule for another time at your earliest convenience".

Comment: @Kristina Lopez: But that *your earliest convenience* introduces two concepts that aren't implicit in the original context (client is in control, OP wants it earlier rather than later), *and* it discards the all-important *near in time to the original appointment*. You also need to bear in mind that *as presented here*, the context is one where OP doesn't care whether the rescheduled appointment is *before* or *after* the original one, so it *might* be highly undesirable for him to use a form of words which implies that earlier (or indeed, *later*) dates might be either preferred or unwanted.

Comment: _Nearby_ is undirected; it's spatial, but experienced time is directed. _A nearby date_ thus means a date on either side of the reference date, like a loose boundary. If you're restricting the discussion to future dates, you should use a directed temporal like _soon_, or a description like what @KristinaLopez suggests.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, your points are well-taken but "nearby" bothers me enough that I'd prefer to go with something a little less succinct like bib's suggestion or like deadrat and JL's "soon".

Comment: @@Kristina Lopez: But as JL also points out, "nearby" is a non-directional metaphoric usage. Alternatives with implied "directionality", or which are relative to time of speaking rather than time of cancelled appointment may be *close*, but they unavoidably distort the meaning to some extent.

Comment: You can't reschedule into the past, only the future, so "ASAP" (as soon as possible) or "soon," or "at your earliest convenience" maybe.

Comment: @developerwjk The OP was talking about discussing a proposed time relative to the *original date*. Supposing the original date was 2 weeks into the future, a day earlier than that would still be in the future at the time of the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the use of **adjacent** to suggest a time(frame) close to your original appointment:

> a :  not distant :  nearby
>
> b :  having a common endpoint or border
>
> c :  immediately preceding or following

(See the "full definition" section at http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjacent)

> "Are you available any time **adjacent** to our original meeting?"

This should (hopefully) satisfy the comments that the word you're seeking should suggest either a time before or after the original appointment.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first time on the site, and I am so impressed by the variety of thoughtful, insightful responses.  Thank you!

For my purposes, "adjacent to the original time" is ideal.  Other responses like soon, asap, at soonest convenience, etc. include a hint of urgency.  In fact, if someone cancels a meeting that is two weeks distant, I don't want them to reschedule "soon", but rather as close as possible to the original time (either before or after).

Many thanks to all!